# Why with this unexpected end of file error?

Tags: php

Im a new beginner. I have been working on this for 3 days, before i ask the question here. I already googled everything but the problem is not same as mine eventhought have the same error. Please help me.

The error is -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp2\htdocs\LI\Assignment1\edit_projek3.php on line 33
>   By line 33, it's mean the last line.

```
    <html>
<head><title>EDIT PROJEK</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","");
if(!$dbcon){
die("Tidak berjaya disambungkan: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan",$dbcon);
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateProject = "UPDATE projek SET kod_projek='$_POST[kodBaru], tajuk_projek='$_POST[tajukBaru]', norujukan='$_POST[rujukanBaru]' WHERE kod_projek='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateProject, $dbcon);
$listProject = "SELECT * FROM projek";
$queryProject = mysql_query($listProject,$dbcon);
echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
<tr>
<th>Kod Projek</th>
<th>Tajuk Projek</th>
<th>No Rujukan</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($queryProject)){
echo "<form action=edit_projek3.php method=POST>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `if(isset($_POST['update'])){` is missing a closing bracket. Not sure if it's the way you pasted your code but you should looking into indenting your code for easier readability.

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that you have not close one bracket. You have not close the `if(isset($_POST['update'])){` bracket. Use the code below

```
 <html>
<head><title>EDIT PROJEK</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","");
if(!$dbcon){
die("Tidak berjaya disambungkan: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan",$dbcon);
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateProject = "UPDATE projek SET kod_projek='$_POST[kodBaru], tajuk_projek='$_POST[tajukBaru]', norujukan='$_POST[rujukanBaru]' WHERE kod_projek='$_POST[hidden]'";
mysql_query($UpdateProject, $dbcon);
$listProject = "SELECT * FROM projek";
$queryProject = mysql_query($listProject,$dbcon);
echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
<tr>
<th>Kod Projek</th>
<th>Tajuk Projek</th>
<th>No Rujukan</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($queryProject)){
echo "<form action=edit_projek3.php method=POST>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=kodBaru value=" . $record['kod_projek'] . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for take your time to helping me, @Utkarsh . The error now has disappear but nothing is comes out as the out put now. There is another error in my code?

Comment: I checked out your code and found out that nothing is wrong. Make sure you are getting the POST data. By echoing it

Comment: I only got the blank screen, no output. I've copied the code that you already corrected. @Utkarsh

Comment: Check weather the data is in the database or not. And also check weather the post data is been send to php